# Can I replace 1 switch of a 3-switch box with a Motion Detector switch

Tags: switch, light

Our bathrooms have a 3-switch box: 1-sink lights, 1-shower light, 1-fan. My son doesn't shut off the light, so it is on all night (or all day).

Can I replace one of the light switches with a motion detector switch?

thanks,
len

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box?

Comment: How about a timer?

Comment: 1. Replace bulb wth efficient LED  2. Stop caring about light left on.   Srsly, we burn the fan  light in our bathroom 24x7, for safety for the elders.  It's 5 watts or about $5/year.

Comment: a) the inside of the box is a standard 3 switch bathroom set-up.

Comment: I believe my two Comments address my issue quite well. I received some really good suggestions and very quickly. It looks like addressing the wattage of the light bulbs is the easiest and most efficient solution. I just think it would be nice if someone make a two or three switch box that would hold a regular switch and a Motion detector switch. thanks to all for your quick replies, len

Comment: Are any of the 3-way switches on a wall exterior to the bathroom?

Answer (score -3):

A three way switch is a single pole double throw switch and will not work with a single pole single throw switch like a motion sensor switch. A three way switch has two switch legs and one common lead. You could wire the motion sensor in series with one of the commons of either switch and the light would stay off when no motion was sensed. Once motion was sensed the three way switched would work normally.

Comment: When the OP is asking about a 3-way switch box he is referring to a triple wide electrical box for three separate switches. You are totally confusing the issue at hand with a "three way switch" which has nothing to do with the OPs question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying for me. Swapping out a light switch for a Motion Detector switch doesn't seem to be an viable option without making the switch box hole larger and installing three separate switches (one being a Motion Detector switch).  Thanks for your help, all.  len